# Switch current fragment on item click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to write a file manager for android as an university project. My idea is to use fragments in it to create a tabbed vew for it with a viewpager. Practically, the first view you get when you load the app is a path selection fragment, where you have sdcard, music, etc. That fragment contains a listview of said folders. When I click on an item, i want another fragment to be added to the pager, and that works fine. But I also want the current fragment to be replaced with a grid view of the "clicked" folder. That doesn't work. I use an arraylist of File[] to store files in each folder i selected. I also added methods inside the fragment adapter to add and replace fragments in my fragment arraylist. Tried with transaction and with my list, the list is correctly updated but the view is not. The following code is the method inside my fragment adapter to replace a fragment. It is called inside an onItemclicklistenr set to my listview:

```
    public void replaceFragment(SherlockFragment newFragment, int pos) {
    SherlockFragment old=fragments.get(pos);
    fragments.set(pos, newFragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

I read several answers about this issue, tried almost everything, nothing seems to work. Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found an horrible solution. After updating the fragment list (without fragmenttransaction) I re-set the adapter for the view pager and restore the current Item. This way I force the fragments layouts to be built. Not beautiful, but whatever. This is the interface that gets called onclick:

```
@Override
    public void onPathSelected(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("positioninsideintfc", Integer.toString(position));
            firstrun.add(true);
            int current=mPager.getCurrentItem();
            root=(File) filepaths.get(position);
            fragmentfilelists.add(root.listFiles());
            initpath=MainActivity.root.getAbsolutePath();
            Gridfragment newfrag=Gridfragment.newInstance(current);
            mAdapter.addFragment(Selectpathfragment.newInstance(current+1));
            mAdapter.replaceFragment(newfrag, current);
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mPager.setCurrentItem(current);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn your `Activity` to speak the language your frament use. In general your Activity should implement `Interface` which then your fragments will use for communication. So in your case, when user tap the list item, the fragment with listview shall tell its parent Actity (using said interface) something like "user clicked on this". And your parent activity should do the rest, replacing/adding fragments. Your fragment, like in OOP, shall be not aware of existence of other fragments.

Comment: Just implemented your solution. Created an "onselectpathlistener" interface implemented by my main activity. Then tried to move the code I had insde the onclick listener to be in the interface. As before, the list of fragments gets updated correctly, the new fragment is correctly added, but the view remains unchanged...

Comment: I noticed that if I press the home button and then reload the application, the grid view appears correctly. Maybe I implemented this wrong, I inflate a layout from an xml file and set the adapter, all this onCreateView, that seems to be called only when i bring back the activity from the background. Did I get something wrong?